# Update MongoDb Class property names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb-.net-driver

Our website is in production (phase 1)and we use MongoDB with Asp.Net MVC. 
But for Phase 2, we need to make some changes to our Schema Classes like change property names and change some data types.

If anyone can point us in the right direction to write a migration script to update all property names to new names and the data types to new types , that would be great !

Is it possible to write a small C# app to get all the collections from the database and update the property names to new names and change the data types ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I recently did exactly this.

Firstly, rename all your classes in your code.
Then use the mongo shell with [renameCollection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/renameCollection+Command)
If this is a one-time operation, no need to script it.

Saying that, you could of course write a .js file with all your renames in, so that it can be executed again on another server easily if you need to

Comment: Hello, does renameCollection renames the properties inside the class ?

Answer (score 0):

As alexjamesbrown, first rename the properties in your class.

Then, you can create a simple rudimentary Versioning structure for your Mongo db.  Store the latest version, and then on application startup check the version, and look for files with a version later than that using reflection.  Then you can simply keep files of a format such as this in your source tree:

```
public class Version3 : MongoMigration
{
    public Version3 (MongoDatabase database) : base(database) { }

    public override double Version
    {
        get { return 3; }
    }

    protected override void PerformUpgrade()
    {
        var collectionToUpdate = Database.GetCollection("MyCollection");
        var allDocuments = collectionToUpdate .FindAll();

        foreach (var document in allDocuments )
        {
            var oldFieldValue = document ["OldFieldName"];
            if (!document.Contains("NewFieldName"))
                document.Add("NewFieldName", oldFieldValue);
            document.Remove("OldFieldName");

            collectionToUpdate.Save(document);
        }
    }
}
```